# Sort array by date before pagination after readdir

Tags: php, pagination, readdir

I have code to display images from a folder with pagination. I need to alter it so that it displays the newest image first on page one, and the oldest on the last page. I have tried a few methods but nothing seems to work. Please help!

```
$mydir = opendir($maindir) ;
$limit = 78;
$offset = ((int)$_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0; 
$files = array();
$page='';
$exclude = array( ".", "..", "index.php",".htaccess","guarantee.gif") ;
while($fn = readdir($mydir))
{
    if (!in_array($fn, $exclude)) 
    {
        $files[] = $fn;;
    }
}
closedir($mydir);
sort($files);
$newICounter = (($offset + $limit) <= sizeof($files)) ? ($offset + $limit) : sizeof($files);
for($i=$offset;$i<$newICounter;$i++) {
    //SHOW THE IMAGES HERE
};
```

Comment: Did you try `$files[$i]`?

Comment: How is your date information encoded? Filename prefix? i.e. `2015_08_23_Blah.jpg` or filesystem metadata (last modified/creation date)?

What is the _specific_ problem you are having? Ordering the images? Or actually displaying them?

Comment: The issue is ordering them. I cant use file name, it must be ordered by system creation data on a windows server.

Answer (score 0):

You can order the files by its file modification time:

```
<?php

    $mydir = opendir($maindir) ;
    $limit = 78;
    $offset = ((int)$_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0; 
    $files = array();
    $page='';
    $exclude = array( ".", "..", "index.php",".htaccess","guarantee.gif") ;

    while(false !== ($img_file = readdir($mydir))){
        if (!in_array($img_file, $exclude)){
            # <<<<<<<<<<<<<< CHANGE 1 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            //Put the creation date as the array's key:
            $files[date('Y m d, H:i:s',filemtime($img_file))] = $img_file;
        }
    }

    closedir($mydir);

    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<< CHANGE 2 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  
    //order files by date in ascending order:
    ksort($files);
    //reverse the array (you need the newest files first)
    $files = array_reverse($files, false);      
        /*NOTE: in this point you have your images in $files array which are ordered by the file modification time of each file, so you only need the code to display them. I don't know how are you displaying your images, but that is the easiest part of the problem.*/
    foreach($files as $a_image){
echo "<img href='" . $maindir . $a_image ."' alt='Image not found' width='100%' height='auto'/>"; 
}
?>
```

It's difficult get the exact creation time of a file in all platforms. So I recommend to you that concatenate the current date with the file name when you create the file.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I can't get your code to work. I'm not a php developer so I'm finding this task a little difficult. With your code, I cannot get the images to display...

Comment: ?>

 <div class="large-2 medium-4 column"><a href="get-image.php?file=<?php print $files[$i]; ?>" ><img src="get-image?file=<?php print $files[$i]; ?>" width="100%" height="auto"><br /><small><?php echo date ("d/m/Y-H:i:s", filemtime($maindir."/".$files[$i])); ?></small></a>
    
    </div>


    <?php
}

Comment: I made some changes in the code. The code is going to search images in a directory with name $maindir. Then is going to loop through the directory and read all the files (I suppossed that all are image files) and save the image's name in an array called $files. Then ksort sort the files by the file's modification time of the current file. Then see "NOTE:" comment.